# Crash on resuming app within 11 seconds after exit(0)

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data, crash, multitasking

I have an app that imports data on start using Core Data. In this part of the app, I have disabled resuming (multitasking) by calling exit(0) in applicationDidEnterBackground when a flag is set. E.g.:

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    if (allowResuming==NO){
        NSLog(@"Terminating...");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

If I then attempt to 'resume' the app (by pressing its icon) within 11 seconds of having pressed the Home button (and, therefore, exit(0) having been called), the app crashes. This doesn't happen when running through the debugger, but the crash logs suggest that it looks like the app is trying to resume the data import where it left off, which, of course, is not what I want.

Attempting to 'resume' the app again straight after this crash (i.e. within a second) is successful.

If I attempt to 'resume' the app after 11 seconds, it's fine.

I would be really grateful if anyone has any ideas and/or can point me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you should be doing `exit(0)`. To disable Multitasking, set the key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key in Info.plist to YES. For details, see the section **Opting Out of Background Execution** at
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW1.

To discard the partial work done when the app leaves foreground, add a listener for `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification or UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`. In the handler method, you could do something like-

```
[self discardPartialWorkDone];
```

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: Thanks Akshay, but I need to allow resuming in another part of the app.

Comment: What problem do you foresee if you allow the app to be suspended? Unless you explicitly write code to execute in the background, all your statements will be suspended & resumed when the app becomes active again.

Comment: If I allow the app to resume, it crashes in the same way. I want to make sure the data is complete and consistent. So, if the import is interrupted then I need the app to start from scratch (dump all current data and re-import)

Comment: You should never call exit(0). This causes all sorts of weird bugs and behaviours with multitasking and is explicitly disallowed by the iOS guidelines.

Comment: Edited the answer to take care of this.

Comment: Thanks Akshay. Sounds like the best way forward. I'll probably set a flag when notified, then every pass through every loop of the import process I'll just look for this flag and, if set, will abandon the import. The priorities have shifted for me now, but if/when I get a chance to try this out I'll let everyone know the results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `exit(0)` like Akshay said. In addition to that Apple will probably reject your App, because Apps which consist of code which interrupt the App like this wont be approved.

Comment: Thanks Malte O., but this is an enterprise app so it won't need Apple's approval.